# Is there a command to convert byte data to text?

Tags: command-line

This is my data :

åæ¤ ±‚ã „nUv eiliÃ t©na
g›èé™›£¾èã¼€‚U eng eroniullðeŸ ¸uq ilpnoeg
,°æã´®Ÿé ³eLb urtid  e'laeðuŒŸ
Š

Thank you

Comment: Well this is text, a UTF-16 text. But likely you want this converted to ASCII, so you want something that reads individual sets of 8 bits and interprets them as characters. For that you may need at best Python or Perl, or C at worst. Although probably utilities like that exist already.

Comment: I think before someone can answer your question, you have to give others much more information.  For example, where is your data from (i.e., what program) and why do you think it is binary data that could be converted to text?

Answer (score 3):

An interesting question Sandra, and Sergiy is on the right track but I wanted to answer the question in a little more depth, and since you tagged this with **command-line** I thought I would explore it with the data you provided in your question. I created a file "askubuntu-q1085049.bin" containing only the data from your question:

~$ cat askubuntu-q1085049.bin

åæ¤ ±‚ã „nUv eiliÃ t©na g›èé™›£¾èã¼€‚U eng eroniullðeŸ ¸uq ilpnoeg ,°æã´®Ÿé ³eLb urtid e'laeðuŒŸ

I then ran the command **file** to see if it was identifiable by **"magic numbers"**:

~$ file askubuntu-q1085049.bin
askubuntu-q1085049.bin: UTF-8 Unicode text, with no line terminato

Since this doesn't appear to be human-readable text but some kind of binary data I took a look at it with **dhex**:

~$ dhex askubuntu-q1085049.bin

```
─[       0/      8D]───────────────────────────────────[askubuntu-q1085049.bin]─
       0     c3 a5 c3 a6 c2 a4 20 c2  b1 e2 80 9a c3 a3 20 e2   ...... ....... .
      10     80 9e 6e 55 76 20 65 69  6c 69 c3 83 20 74 c2 a9   ..nUv eili.. t..
      20     6e 61 20 67 e2 80 ba c3  a8 c3 a9 e2 84 a2 e2 80   na g............
      30     ba c2 a3 c2 be c3 a8 c3  a3 c2 bc e2 82 ac e2 80   ................
      40     9a 55 20 65 6e 67 20 65  72 6f 6e 69 75 6c 6c c3   .U eng eroniull.
      50     b0 65 c5 b8 20 c2 b8 75  71 20 69 6c 70 6e 6f 65   .e.. ..uq ilpnoe
      60     67 20 2c c2 b0 c3 a6 c3  a3 c2 b4 c2 ae c5 b8 c3   g ,.............
      70     a9 20 c2 b3 65 4c 62 20  75 72 74 69 64 20 65 27   . ..eLb urtid e'
      80     6c 61 65 c3 b0 75 c5 92  c5 b8 20 c5 a0            lae..u.... ..
      90
      A0
      B0
      C0
      D0
      E0
      F0
     100
     110
     120
     130
     140
     150
 1Goto   2Search 3Next   4Prev   5HexCal 6       7       8       9Undo   0Quit
```

Finally I used a Unicode tool,**gucharmap**, to determine which Unicode characters these are to see if it provided any additional info (Unicode characters can be 1-4 bytes long, or more - see **info utf-8**.) You will need to have a GUI of some kind in order to run **gucharmap**. As the screenshot shows the character "æ", is part of the Unicode Latin-1 Supplement, with further details:

"U+00E6 LATIN SMALL LETTER AE = latin small ligature ae(1.1); ash (from Old English æsc) - Danish, Norwegian, Icelandic, Faroese, Old English, ..."

[Screenshot of **gucharmap** in use.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOtNj.png)

Hopefully this will answer your original question as I understood it. In summary:

- This appears to be a binary stream, not human readable text.
- The **file** command identifies this as a stream of UTF-8 text, not a known program or other file type recognized by **"magic numbers"**.
- We also used the command-line command **dhex** to look at a binary dump of the file in question. If you have a GUI available you might try **ghex** instead because it can switch between "big-ending" and "little-endian" encoding; and also between 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit, and 64-bit views of the data.
- We also looked at the Unicode formatting of the characters using the GUI tool **gucharmap**

That's as far as I can go in my answer since I'm not sure where the data you supplied in the question came from or if it is complete.